# Invoking methods on interfaces with generics

Tags: kotlin

The following is a very simple illustration of what I'm trying to do:

```
interface Event {
    fun value(): Int
}

class Event1: Event {
    override fun value() = 1
}

class Event2: Event {
    override fun value() = 2
}

interface EventConsumer<T> where T: Event {
    fun consume(event: T)
}

class Event1Consumer: EventConsumer<Event1> {
    override fun consume(event: Event1) {
        println(event.value())
    }
}

class Event2Consumer: EventConsumer<Event2> {
    override fun consume(event: Event2) {
        println(event.value())
    }
}

class EventManager {
    private val consumers: Map<KClass<*>, EventConsumer<*>> = mapOf(
            Event1::class to Event1Consumer(),
            Event2::class to Event2Consumer()
    )

    fun consume(event: Event) {
        val consumer = consumers[event::class]

        consumer?.consume(event)
    }
}
```

The final method call (consumer.consume()) is giving me a compiler error

> Out-projected type 'EventConsumer<*>?' prohibits the use of 'public
>   abstract fun consume(event: T): Unit defined in EventConsumer'

I know that Kotlin is a lot more strict about generics than Java which is probably why it doesn't work, but how would I implement something like this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are building the `consumers` map, it would be safe to make an unchecked cast to the correct generic EventConsumer type:

```
fun <T: Event> consume(event: T) {
    val consumer = consumers[event::class] as? EventConsumer<T>

    consumer?.consume(event)
}
```

Comment: Aaaah so a generic method is what I've been missing... That seems to solve it, thanks!